# User creation using the microsoft MSAL lib

Tags: javascript, python, django, microsoft-graph-api

when I am using the MSAL lib and giving all the parameters that are required , i have created some users in the tenant and when i am trying to access the same users then there is a issue it throws a error as selected user does not exsit in the tenenat , but in acutal the user exists in that tenant  please help me out this is my code

`````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Azure AD B2C Authentication</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/msal@1.4.4/dist/msal.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Azure AD B2C Authentication</h1>
  <button onclick="login()">Login</button>
  <button onclick="logout()">Logout</button>

  <script>
    // MSAL client configuration
    const msalConfig = {
      auth: {
        clientId: ****
        authority:********,
        redirectUri: '*****/',
      },
    };

    const msalClient = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);

    // Login function
    function login() {
      msalClient.loginPopup()
        .then(response => {
          // Login successful
          console.log('Login successful');
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Login failed
          console.error('Login failed');
          console.error(error);
        });
    }

    // Logout function
    function logout() {
      msalClient.logout();
    }

    // Handle redirect callback
    msalClient.handleRedirectCallback((error, response) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Redirect callback error');
        console.error(error);
      } else {
        // Access token and user information available in the response
        const accessToken = response.accessToken;
        const user = response.account;

        // Use the access token for authenticated API calls or other operations
        console.log('Redirect callback successful');
        console.log('Access token:', accessToken);
        console.log('User:', user);
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>````
`````